# How to update without using @Query in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CreditDataFileRepository extends JpaRepository<CreditDataFileEntity, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update passdb.creditdata_files set total_rec=?1, processed_rec=?2, rejected_rec=?3 where filename=?4",nativeQuery=true)
    void updateById(int totalRec, int processedRec, int rejectedRec, String filename);
}
```

I dont want to use @Query annotation and not even jpa save() method.
Is there any other way I can update.

Comment: use jdbc instead

Comment: And how do you think that the update should happen?

Comment: cant we use some custome methods? I dont know how to do it.

Comment: If you mean to have your own code for update but exposed via your JPA repository interface, you probably need a custom interface implementation

Comment: yes custom interface implementation. is there a way to do so? how?

Comment: @shady_bat, https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using the EntityManager you can create and execute queries:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from items where id = ?");
query.setParameter(1, id);

Object[] result = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
```

You can also use the Criteria API:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Item> query = builder.createQuery(Item.class);
Root<Item> root = query.from(Item.class);

query.select(root);
query.where(builder.equals(root.get("id"), id));

Item item = entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```